# How to avoid cannot find package "github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb" error

Tags: docker, go

I want to put my code inside a docker container, I have created dockerfile and when I run, I got an error

```
internal/server/handlers.go:16:2: cannot find package "github.com/lib/pq" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/lib/pq (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/lib/pq (from $GOPATH)
```

but when I launch my code locally without docker by typing go run main.go everything is fine

Comment: It looks like it is Golang code that does not run here, and it is because some dependencies are not found in the docker image, but found in your machine (the dependency probably live inside $GOPATH/src/ folder)

You have few options: (1) build the code on your machine (`go build`) and then put the generated executable in the docker machine. (2) build the code on the docker machine, which means that you need to run `go install` in docker first to install dependencies and then run `go build` or `go run`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you installed all your package inside container. Because your docker container is a different machine with your current computer. You need to make sure that all dependencies package installed in your docker image. For an Dockefile example, install my package at Dockerfile as you can see:

```
FROM golang:latest
# Create working folder
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
RUN apt -y update && apt -y install git
RUN go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
RUN go get github.com/gosimple/slug
RUN go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
RUN go get gopkg.in/russross/blackfriday.v2
RUN go get github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions
WORKDIR /app
```

Now you run `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 your_docker_image_name go run main.go` should work.

Comment: I got an error "docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"go\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
" What does it mean?